# I Need to Make a HashMap Print out words in order of value

Tags: hashmap

This is my code so far, what am I doing wrong? I need to create a `HashMap` of `<Integer,ArrayList<String>>` which will map each word of the test data keyed to the length of the word. Then, display the test String and iterate through the keys and display the words ordered by length. I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong. Should I use an iterator as opposed to a for-each loop, or would that not make much of a difference?

This is my code thus far

```
     HashMap<Integer,String>map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
     // adds values
     map.put(2, "The");
     map.put(8, "Superbowl");
```

Comment: You need to use something other than a HashMap.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is assuming that a `HashMap` makes any sort of guarantee about the order of its keys/values.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an HashMap, you should use a SortedMap: "A Map that further provides a total ordering on its keys" (JDK 1.7 API doc). A TreeMap would do.

A sorted map will return its keys in sorted order. Since your keys are Integer (hence Comparable), their natural ordering is used.

To list the words by increasing length:

```
SortedMap<Integer, List<String>> wordsByLength; // filled somewhere

// Iterates over entries in increasing key order
Set<Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entries = wordsByLength.entrySet(); 
for ( Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry : entries ) {
    int length = entry.getKey();
    List<String> words = entry.getValue();
    // do what you need to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since order is not gauranteed in a HashMap you would need to pull out the keys and sort them before using the sorted key list to loop through the values like so:

```
Map<Integer,String>map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
map.put(2, "The");
map.put(8, "Superbowl");
List<Integer> keyList = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.keySet());
Collections.sort(keyList);
for (Integer key : keyList) {
    System.out.println(map.get(key));
}
```

However in your use case where words are the same length you would end up overwriting previous entries in the Map which would not be what you want. A better solution would be to store the words in a List and sort them using a Comparator that compared String lengths like this:

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
// Loop through adding words if they don't already exist in the List

// sort the List by word length
Collections.sort(words, new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(s1.length()).compareTo(s2.length());
        }
});
//Now loop through sorted List and print words
for (String word : words) {
    System.out.println(word);
}
```